# Files only importing if opened from certain place

Tags: python, import, pygame

I'm making a game for a school project and right now i'm just focusing the getting it to run through the file smoothly.

The files I have are named:

- main.py (Menu File)
- Ship.py(it's the actual game part),
- inputName.py(Where the user inputs their name)
- eztext.py(this is a module that 'inputName.py' is running off)
- certificate.py(A file screen with a menu that print's the persons name/score/etc.)

Main.py links to ship.py when the user selects start

```
menu_items = ('Start', 'Quit')
funcs = {'Start': Difficulty,
         'Quit':quit}
def ship1():
    import Ship1
```

When the user loses the game (Currently i've just set it to when I click the game is over) it is linked to nameInput.py

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
   if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      ship_r.move_ip(-6, 0)
   elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      ship_r.move_ip(+6, 0)
   elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      execfile('nameInput.py')
```

Which when the user writes their name and presses enter, does this

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_BACKSPACE: self.value = self.value[:-1]
    elif event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = True
    elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.value += ' '
    elif event.key == K_RETURN: execfile("Certificate.py")
```

My problem is that if I run the file Ship.py and then "lose" it will run the inputName.py just fine, but if I run from the beginning (main.py) when it imports 'ship.py' and I "lose" it doesn't import the inputName.py it just closes.

Also in calling the other files "execfile("ExampleFile.py")" is the only thing that works for me, is that right? simply doing 'import nameInput' doesn't work for me

Comment: As for me using `execfile()` is stupid idea. Or I should say weird.

Comment: Imported file can be imported again (if nothing changed in that file) - this way Python don't have to import the same file in all subfiles.

Comment: You probably don't even create functions in that file (I will not ask about classes). Show more code then maybe we help you rid that "weird" `execfile()`.

Comment: Here's all the code in one file: http://pastebin.com/DxX7H0JR

Comment: It looks better then I thought :) In some places you will have to move code into (new created) functions and then you would import files only once and run new functions many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of `execfile('nameInput.py')` use

```
import nameInput
nameInput.main()
```

Maybe in `nameInput.py` you will have to move

```
img = pygame.image.load('images/Background_Logo.png')
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
```

inside `main()` - but probably not.

---

In `Ship1.py` you have to create function `main()` (as in `nameInput.py`) and then in place of `execfile('Ship1.py')` and `import Ship1` use

```
import Ship1
Ship1.main()
```

It seems that is all.

You can move all `import` at the beginning of files - if someone will watchs you code he will know what other files he needs.

---

BTW: code could be reorganized to use `pygame.init()` only once - but "that's another story"